# How to define the objective fucntion's variables to be optimized in MATLAB's global optimization toolbox?

Tags: matlab, particle-swarm

I have an objective function `fun` where the input parameter `x` should be optimized by `particleswarm()`: https://de.mathworks.com/help/gads/particleswarm.html

I want to find the optimal values for `x` for defined scenarios. Because of this, besides `x` the function `fun` also accepts scenario parameters `s1` and `s2`:

```
function f = objective(x, s1, s2)
```

Now, how do I tell the solver to just optimize `x` and ignore the input parameters for `s1` and `s2`?

Comment: So particleswarm is an optimizer that you wrote?

Comment: Nope, it belong to the global optimization toolbox of Matlab. Updated the question with a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be something like

```
out = particleswarm(@(x)fun(x,s1,s2))
```

That is how you do it for in-built optimizers like fminunc

Edit: Then, if I understand correctly that particleswarm is an optimizer that you wrote yourself, the function definition of particleswarm would be

```
function [ out ] = particleswarm( func )
```

Alternatively, if you are doing something like BFGS where you need to have an initial guess, x0, that changes in the optimization function, you would call the optimizer with

```
out = particleswarm(x0, @(x)fun(x,s1,s2))
```

and the function definition would be

```
function [ out ] = particleswarm(x0, func )
```